# How do I run the example content type in Plone?

Tags: plone

I am using the Plone framework for developing a content type.
I tried the example given in the [document guide section on the official Plone web site](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/a-simple-at-product/at-product-layout),
but I don't know how to install a product in Plone or how I can otherwise run this example?

Can anyone please tell me, how I can run this example in my Plone server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing Archetype as content type framework

- in [buildout:directory]/src

  paster create -t archetype your.package
- in buildout.cfg

  [...]

  develop +=
    src/your.package

  [...]

  eggs+=
    your.package

  [...]
  zcml+=
    your.package

restart zope
plone control panel -> products addon -> do activate your product.

that's all.

BTW, documentation linked by former answers is a **must**.

Answer (score 3):

See

http://collective-docs.plone.org/tutorials/buildout/creatingpackage.html

In addition look at the mr.developer extension for zc.buildout.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer/1.17

Answer (score 2):

See Development Eggs on the same tutorial, earlier page http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/managing-projects-with-buildout/installing-a-third-party-product